# Regex for duplicate numbers

Tags: regex

I have numbers like this

> {1,2,8},{1,2,8},{4,8,-2},{8,4,1},{8,-6,9},{2,6,1},{6,-5,6},{3,2,9},{8,4,-3},{8,1,9},{7,-5,3},{1,7,3},{1,2,-1},{9,4,6},{2,9,-7},{2,1,4}

and i want to find duplicates like {1,2,8}

I am new to regex and created a simple one but i don't know how to use boundaries

```
-?([0-9]),-?([0-9]),-?([0-9])
```

Comment: Why not deserialize to json and write some comparison code in your preferred language?

Comment: thanks that is possible but i am dying to know how to do it with regex

Comment: This is not a job for `regex`. It can be done but there are other ways that are easier to write and to understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It'd become pretty complicated, if they are not adjacent, but maybe,

```
({\d+(?:,\d+)*,\d+}),\1
```

might be OK to look into for those adjacent.

#### [RegEx Demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/rMutMM/1/)

which we can, I guess, use maybe a positive lookahead:

```
({\d+(?:,\d+)*,\d+})(?=.*(\1))
```

and somehow capture the duplicates.

#### [RegEx Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/OddPea/1/)

---

If you wish to simplify/update/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rMutMM/1/). You can watch the matching steps or modify them in [this debugger link](https://regex101.com/r/rMutMM/1/debugger), if you'd be interested. The debugger demonstrates that how [a RegEx engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_regular_expression_engines) might step by step consume some sample input strings and would perform the matching process.

---

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Most languages have a regExp function that returns all matches into an array. In Javascript you can pass your regExp into `String.match()`, and then use `Array.reduce()` to filter out the unique values:

```js
const str = "{1,2,8},{1,2,8},{4,8,-2},{8,4,1},{8,-6,9},{2,6,1},{6,-5,6},{3,2,9},{8,4,-3},{8,1,9},{7,-5,3},{1,7,3},{1,2,-1},{9,4,6},{2,9,-7},{2,1,4}";

const regExp = /{-?[0-9],-?[0-9],-?[0-9]}/g;
const dup = [];
str.match(regExp).reduce((newArr,cur) => {
   if(newArr.includes(cur)){
      dup.push(cur);
       return newArr; 
   }else{
      return newArr.concat(cur);
   }
  
}, []);

console.log(dup);
```

Answer (score 2):

Such things best done using mathematical operators but just in case you are curious to do using regex, you can do so using this regex,

```
({(?:-?\d+(?:,-?\d+)*)})(?=.*\1)
```

Idea here is to catch the pattern in a group and use a look ahead to check if captured text in group1 is present ahead in the string.

**[Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/aEG5t8/1/)**